# Create Node with Multiple Labels in Py2Neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

To create and save a Node in Neo4J using py2Neo. We do.

```
tx = graph.begin():
node = Node('Label', property='A'})
tx.create(node)
```

As far as create a node with multiple labels. The documentation seems quiet.
Is something possible along the lines.

```
tx = graph.begin()
node = Node(*labels, **properties)
tx.create(node)   # possible
```

Or do we have to resort to `cyper.run` to use raw cypher.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just supply the labels as extra arguments:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph(password="password")

tx = graph.begin()
node = Node("Label1", "Label2", property="A")
tx.create(node)
tx.commit()
```

[image]

Comment: this is equivalent to `Node(*labels, **properties)`